# Does a call to MPI_Barrier affect every thread in an MPI process?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mpi

Does a call to MPI_Barrier affect every thread in an MPI process or only the thread
that makes the call?
   For your information , my MPI application will run with MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to think of this is that MPI_Barrier (and other collectives) are blocking function calls, which block until all processes in the communicator have completed the function.  That, I think, makes it a little easier to figure out what should happen; the function blocks, but other threads continue on their way unimpeded.

So consider the following chunk of code (The shared `done` flag being flushed to communicate between threads is not how you should be doing thread communication, so please don't use this as a template for anything. Furthermore, using a reference to `done` will solve [this bug/optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92672), see the end of comment 2):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int ierr, size, rank;
    int provided;
    volatile int done=0;
    MPI_Comm comm;

    ierr = MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    if (provided == MPI_THREAD_SINGLE) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize with thread support\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,1);
    }

    comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    ierr = MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

    if (rank == 1) sleep(10);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) default(none) shared(rank,comm,done)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
        /* spawn off one thread to do the barrier,... */
        #pragma omp task 
        {
            MPI_Barrier(comm);
            printf("%d -- thread done Barrier\n", rank);
            done = 1;
            #pragma omp flush
        }

        /* and another to do some printing while we're waiting */
        #pragma omp task
        {
            int *p = &done;
            while(!(*p) {
                printf("%d -- thread waiting\n", rank);
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Rank 1 sleeps for 10 seconds, and all the ranks start a barrier in one thread.  If you run this with `mpirun -np 2`, you'd expect the first of rank 0s threads to hit the barrier, and the other to cycle around printing and waiting -- and sure enough, that's what happens:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./threadbarrier
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread waiting
1 -- thread waiting
0 -- thread done Barrier
1 -- thread done Barrier
```

Comment: +1 for a good example. A call to Barrier will only block the thread that called it, and not all threads need to call Barrier to let the process complete the call.

Comment: Any idea why in my case this program never stops? ('done' variable is never read as 1 in 'while(!done)' part. I have added there '#pragma omp flush (done)' but it does not help. My compiler gcc 6.3.0 / Mac OS.